# Calendar app not able to add subscription to "on my mac"

Tags: macos, ical

**How do I get apple calendar to add calendar subscriptions to my greyed out "On My Mac" section?**

I am not able to add calendar subscriptions to my "on my mac" subscription section, instead I am forced to put all subscriptions into the iCloud section (greyed out "On My Mac" section). Earlier I was able to do this without problems.

[image: calendar app "On My Mac" greyed out]

Comment: Is On My Mac enabled in Calendar's Accounts list?

Comment: Do you mean on the side where I can add calendars or Calendar/preferences.../accounts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Calendar->Preferences->Acccounts, disable iCloud.

Then create a new calendar, giving it a name that doesn't conflict with any of the calendars in your iCloud.

Now you can re-enable the iCloud account.

The new calendar (under "On My Mac") remains.

Comment: Just for clarification this works for adding calendars as well as adding subscribed calendars. Thank you very much for the simple answer :D